# using an arduino wifi as webserver

Tags: java

Im trying to use an arduino wifi board as a simple webserver for a java programming runnig at the PC.
The webserver is the webserver sketch from the arduino example library. At the PC I have built a small Java program witht eh following code:

```
URL   url URL("http://10.0.0.11:80");
HttpURLConnection conn  = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput        (true);
conn.setDoInput         (true);
conn.setRequestProperty ("Content-Type", "text/xml8");

InputStream   is = conn.getInputStream();
```

The last statement causes an error with the following error-message:
*Server returned HTTP response code: 501 for URL: http://10.0.0.11:80/home.html*

Why do I get this error-message?

Comment: Is [this arduino link](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=166448.0) useful?

Comment: I think the content-type may be mispelled (text/xml8) ... shouldn't it be text/xml or text/html ???

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have tried the 'text/html' option and got the same error code.